# How to save state(time when it was paused) of every video in exo player to resume it afterwards

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am not able to save the state of each video respectively. Currently, when I press back from a playing video, I save the last time of that video and when I click on any other video it resumes to the last saved position. But I want each position to be saved independently.

**What I am doing:**

```
        @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    videoView.pause();

    mPlayVideoWhenForegrounded = videoView.getPlayer().getPlayWhenReady();

// Store off the last position our player was in before we paused it.
    mLastPosition = videoView.getPlayer().getCurrentPosition();

    // Pause the player
    videoView.getPlayer().setPlayWhenReady(false);

    //Here I am saving the last position in the database
    sqLiteDatabaseHandler.add(new Contact(mLastPosition,""));   
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23) {
        videoView.resume();
    }
    //getting db values
    results = (ArrayList) sqLiteDatabaseHandler.getAll();
    if(results.size()>0){

        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            //value from databse of mLastPosition saved in onBackPressed()
            seekto=results.get(i).getmLastPosition();
        }
        //seekto returns int value as 5604 or 7400
        if(seekto>1000){
            videoView.getPlayer().seekTo(seekto);
        }
    }
}
```

**What is the issue I am facing:**

With the above logic, I am able to pause and resume the video from where left off. But it resumes each video from the *mLastPosition* saved of any video. I want to save each video position *differently*. Please give me a logic on how can I store each video updated *mLastPosition* to resume it from the same. Basically, I want each should resume from a different time where it was paused.

Comment: Commenting for better reach and i also follow this question.

Comment: You should save to the database not only position but also an identifier of a video. It could be id, UUID, filename, etc. Anything that you have

Comment: thanks for the comment. Sir, I tried that also but I wasn't able to differentiate each video latest time! Let's say i saved the title with mlasttime, then in onstart() method how should i resume a specific video with that saved title name to differentiate?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the current window, the current position, and possibly the state of playWhenReady each in a variable, so you can resume the player later. We can do something like the below:

**Store the player position in onPause:**

```
public void onPause() { 
    super.onPause();
    player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    if (player != null) {
        mLastPosition = player.getCurrentPosition();
        …
    }
}
```

**Save the last playback position into the bundle:**

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle currentState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(currentState);
    currentState.putLong(SELECTED_POSITION, mLastPosition);
    currentState.putParcelable(KEY_TRACK_SELECTOR_PARAMETERS, trackSelectorParameters);
    currentState.putInt(KEY_WINDOW, startWindow);
    currentState.putLong(KEY_POSITION, startPosition);
    currentState.putBoolean(KEY_AUTO_PLAY, startAutoPlay);
}
```

**Initiate the player again in onResume and set seek to the last position of the player:**

```
public void onResume() {
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    super.onResume();
    //initiateExoPlayerPlayer();
     if(mLastPosition!=0 && player!=null){
         player.seekTo(mLastPosition);
     }
}
```

Have a look [here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/demos/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo/PlayerActivity.java#L562).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have solved my query using the where clause while saving the video title and with the mLastPosition.